# xdebug with puphpet on mac and windows7 with phpstorm

Tags: vagrant, phpstorm, xdebug, puphpet

I'm generating a vagrantbox via puphpet.com (Ubuntu Trusty 14.04, nginx, php5.5, mysql, redis, (..)) - this works fine.

On my mac I just need to toggle this little icon as displayed in the following figure in phpstorm. Nothing else, I can directly start to set my break-points and it works. No further xdebug settings within the VM or phpstorm.

[image: start listening for debug connections]

My problem is, that I'm not able to set this up within a vagrant windows (7) environment. I've googled and tried serveral tutorials - but it still does not work.

Any tipps for the windows environment? Here is my puphpet config.yaml https://gist.github.com/wiesson/2fb2e8ebfef7f8d4e800

Is this maybe related to the firewall?

Comment: Quite possibly: just enable "phone handle" icon in PhpStorm and try to connect from your VM to IDE on xdebug port. If it does not -- then firewall most likely be the reason: it could be on Windows side as well as VM side. Second thing to check -- make sure that it is PhpStorm who listens on that port -- maybe you have another app listening that instead. Use `netstat` or any other GUI utility (from SysInternals, for example)

Answer (score 6):

Two things.

You do need to enable PhpStorm through the public firewall. I have no idea why, as I've set my local network as home. Find the "Allow programs to communicate through Windows Firewall", scroll down to PhpStorm, tick the Public checkbox and click Ok.

You may still have issues, as your xdebug setup is wrong. Here's what I have on both my Mac and my PC.

```
xdebug:
  install: '1'
  settings:
    xdebug.default_enable: '1'
    xdebug.remote_autostart: '0'
    xdebug.remote_connect_back: '1'
    xdebug.remote_enable: '1'
    xdebug.remote_handler: dbgp
    xdebug.remote_port: '9000'
    xdebug.remote_host: 192.168.56.101
    xdebug.remote_mode: req
    xdebug.idekey: PHPSTORM
```

I am assuming you've already [set up the bookmarks](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/marklets/) in your Browser.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this tomorrow! (Btw on my Mac I don't need any bookmarks)

Comment: Which version of windows do you use? Can you post a screenshot of your firewall settings?

Comment: Windows 7 home edition. Will post a screenshot tonight

Comment: Chrome has also a great Xdebug helper extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xdebug-helper/eadndfjplgieldjbigjakmdgkmoaaaoc?hl=de